# None unity PBR assets and Standard shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, pbr

We are a small studio consisting of two devs, we have bought all our assets at the Asset store but now we need to expand our model database so we also look at Turbosquid. We only want PBR assets becasuse they look so much better in unity 5.

Many assets on Turbosquid comes with these textures

[image]

Albedo / metalic and Norm. have their corresponding place in the Unity standard shader, but what about Roghness and AO, any tutorials on converting assets like these into Unity 5 standard shader?

In Unity 5 we have something called Smoothness, does that correspond to Roughness, if yes, any tips how to include that as alpha on the Metallic texture?

[image]